# how to middle vertical-align using bootstrap input-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked at other posts on how to vertical-align: middle with bootstrap.  That works fine.

What I'm trying to do is to create a search bar with a "go" button as per standard bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) that is vertically aligned in a div as seen here:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 vcenter">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```

Problem I have is the minute I try to add in css to vertically align it, everything goes crazy and it's no longer aligned:

```
.vcenter {
    height: 375px;
    line-height: 300px;
}

.vcenter input, .vcenter span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting both the input and button to be aligned middle?

Comment: Yep. basically want it to look the the bootstrap example in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the code:

Remove the css following css:

```
 .vcenter {
    height: 375px;
    line-height: 300px;
}

.vcenter input, .vcenter span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and update as simple:

```
.vcenter {
    margin-top:50px;
}

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12 vcenter">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  </div>
</div>
```